# How do I pass over a data variable to show only associated data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, view

This probably a fairly basic question but I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails.

In my Ruby on Rails application I have a cinema system. What I am trying to do:

On the films/show page the user has the option to 'Book' a seat for the film, when they do this I want them to go to the showings/index page where they can select a showing for that film. The problem I am having is get the showings/index page to show only showings for that film, as currently it is just listing all the showings in the database.

This is films/show page where the showings are listed and I'm trying to pass over the film data:

```
<% if not @film.showings.blank? %>
    <% @film.showings.each do |showing| %>
        <%= showing.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y") %>@ <%= showing.show_time.strftime("%H:%M") %>
        <% if logged_in? %>
            <%= link_to 'Book', showings_path(@showing) %>
       <% end %></br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And the showings/index page:

```
<% @showings.each do |showing| %>
    <tr id='sizeable'>
        <td><%= showing.show_date %></td>
        <td><%= showing.show_time %></td>
        <td><% if not showing.film.blank? %><%= showing.film.title %><% end %></td>
        <td style="padding-right:65px">
        <%= link_to 'Delete', showing_path(showing), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

My current routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :showings

get 'sessions/new'
get 'sessions/create'
get 'sessions/destroy'
controller :sessions do
    get  'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    get 'logout' => :destroy
end

resources :users


get 'films/index'
get 'categories/index'
get 'certificates/index'

resources :films
resources :categories
resources :certificates
resources :showings
resources :bookings
resources :seats
resources :screens
root 'films#index'

post 'films/search', to: 'films#search'

post 'films/display_products_by_genre', :to => 'films#display_products_by_genre'
get 'films/display_products_by_genre', :to => 'films#display_products_by_genre'

post 'seats/display_seats_by_screen', :to => 'seats#display_seats_by_screen'
get 'seats/display_seats_by_screen', :to => 'seats#display_seats_by_screen'

post 'screens/display_screens_by_showing', :to => 'screens#display_screens_by_showing'
get 'screens/display_screens_by_showing', :to => 'screens#display_screens_by_showing'

post 'films/multi_find', :to => 'films#multi_find'
get 'films/multi_find', :to => 'films#multi_find'

post 'seats/multi_find', :to => 'seats#multi_find'
get 'seats/multi_find', :to => 'seats#multi_find'
post 'screens/multi_find', :to => 'screens#multi_find'
get 'screens/multi_find', :to => 'screens#multi_find'


match '*a', to: 'errors#routing', via: [:get, :post]
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: will the showing index always show showings related to a certain movie? if so then it's better to make the showing as a nested resource inside movie, so the url will be `/films/5/showings` and the index will use `film_id` to filter the showings, but you'll loose the bare `/showings` route, will that be suitable for you ?

Comment: Yes that would be fine. Can you please show me how to do that, but please try and make it simple, I do not have a strong understanding of ruby on rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we configure the routing

```
resources :films do
  resources :showings
end
```

Then we configure the controller

```
class ShowingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @showings = Showing.where(film_id: params[:film_id])
  end
end
```

No need to update the views, it should work fine

Make sure to check all your old showings routes, you might need to update them, if you find it's a lot of trouble to fix all of them, we can create all resources actions under `/showings` and only move the `:index` under `films`

Comment: I've uploaded what my routes currently looks like, do I need to change the line: `<%= link_to 'Book', showings_path(@showing) %>` because at the minute, after adding in your changes, it'll go to the showings/index page but not showings are listed?

Comment: why do you want to pass an object to the index path? i think you should pass the film not the showing, `showings_path(film: @film)`

Comment: Yeah you're right, I've changed it to what you recommended but it didn't work, so I changed `(film: @film)` to `(film_id: @film)` and it works. Thank you!!!

Comment: just make sure to check the rest of the routes/views that have showings, if you get any problems tell me

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, `variable` and `@variable` are two different things, so in your `films/show` page you're iterating over each `@film.showings` and there's a local `showing` variable (which you **do** actually use in the first line of your loop) but in your `link_to 'Book'` you use `@showing` which either has no value, or has the wrong value (if you set it to one of the showings in your controller).

The fix is to replace `@showing` with the `showing` local variable in that `link_to`

Comment: Changing: `<%= link_to 'Book', showings_path(@showing) %>` to `<%= link_to 'Book', showings_path(showing) %>` didn't work.

Comment: "didn't work" is not useful to us (and therefore to you). what actually happened?

Comment: Secondly: the above is bug in your code - you need to fix it even if you do the other fix (that will fix which showings are to be displayed)

Comment: Wow, @TarynEast, I met with you once in Chatswood about a Perl job in my small business. Such a small world. Thanks for backing my play here :)

Comment: ...or maybe it was Ruby, I can't remember :)

Comment: cool! yeah sounds about right. Sure is a small world :) Ruby is more likely - but I did go for a couple of short-term perl jobs while I was waiting for my british visa to come through...